# How do I call a method that has as parameter a custom-designed object with Postman API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

I am a newbie in using Postman for testing RESTful endpoints in Spring applications. Until now I only invoked simple methods, without parameters, which return only some String messages. I also read some topics about invoking methods that have parameters of basic types (int, String).
Currently I have to create a Spring project for searching some jobs data stores in a Postgres DB. The controller method is this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Search job", notes = "With this request you can search for jobs", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "Bearer")})
@PostMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<?> search(@RequestBody JobSearchEntity searchCriteria) {
    log.info("JobsController -> search method");
    //JobSearchEntity jobSearchEntity = modelMapper.map(jobSearch, JobSearchEntity.class);
    List<JobEntity> jobs = jobService.searchJobs(searchCriteria);
    //log.info(String.format("Job found: %s ", jobSearch));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jobs);
}
```

As it can be seen, it takes as parameter an object of a custom-designed class from my project, which is shown below:

```
@Data
public class JobSearchEntity {
private String jobTitle;
private String jobDescription;
private List<String> technology;
private List<String> programmingLanguage;
private List<String> jobMobility;
private List<String> jobType;
private Integer paymentMin;
private Integer paymentMax;
}
```

Does someone please tell me how can I test such a method with Postman (or even more, is it possible to test such Restful endpoints)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that your endpoint accepts JSON objects.
If so that is quite straightforward.

Go to the body tab of your request and configure it like this:

[image]

In the text area below you must insert your "custom" object in JSON format.

e.g:

```json
{
    "jobTitle": "test",
    "jobDescription": "test",
    "technology": ["test"],
    "programmingLanguage": ["test"],
    "jobMobility": ["test"],
    "jobType": ["test"],
    "paymentMin": 0,
    "paymentMax": 0,
}
```

Comment: what...?!?! enter my parameter object in JSON format? that is the only option for this problem...???

Comment: Why are you so surprised? This is a RESTful API...

Comment: Ok... so should I understand that, in the real application scenario, the object parameter of the method that is sent to the server when method is called is serialized like a JSON also in this manner? Or not...?!?

Comment: Yes exactly. REST APIs use HTTP as a communication protocol and as a communication "language" JSON. I would suggest you take a look at this article https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/

Comment: And please accept (by clicking the tick mark) and upvote if the answer is helpful.

Comment: Yes, the answer is useful but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to cast a vote... i hope SO will soon increase my grade over 15 in order to do that... but many thanks again !

Comment: You should be able to accept though. No problem :)